# How would I make this Java 7 compatible?

Tags: java, maven, generics, java-8, java-7

I have an interface that basically looks like this:

```
public interface ISetting<T> {
    public T getDefault();
    public T value();
    public void set(T value);
    public String getName();

    public default String getValueName() {
        Object obj = value();
        if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
            return (boolean)obj ? "Yes" : "No"; 
        }

        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

And then in another class I have a list of `ISetting<?>`

```
private List<ISetting<?>> settings = Arrays.asList(
        new ClassMode(),
        new EndMode(),
        new PlayerLives(),
        new JoinMidGame(),
        new ScoreboardDisplay(),
        new LifePerKill(),
        new ExplosiveBullets(),
        new ReloadTime());
```

And this all works perfectly! However, the platform where I use my code doesn't support Java 8, so I have to use Java 7, and here's where the problems come.

**If I set the Maven target to 1.7, like this in my pom.xml:**

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

Then the code compiles perfectly with no errors or anything. However, when I try to run the code, it gives me this error:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method getValueName in class
>   net/uniqraft/murder/match/settings/ISetting has illegal modifiers: 0x1

I tried to Google it but couldn't find anything that I understood or seemed to be applicable in my case.

**So, I thought, I'll just make the entire codebase into Java 7:**

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
```

The first error I see is:

> Default methods are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above

Which is incredibly annoying and I don't know how to bypass that. A lot of my code is dependent on default implementations. I guess I just have to use abstract classes instead?

But the more problematic error I see is on the `List<Setting<?>>` I have:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ISetting<? extends Object&Comparable<?>&Serializable>> to List<ISetting<?>>`

I have no idea what that means or how to fix it. The quickfix Eclipse offers are of no help.

In case the you need to see the full non-stripped ISetting class or the full stacktrace, I put them externally as they're rather spacey:

- [ISetting.java](https://gist.github.com/VapidLinus/da9d9bc20ccef733bbde)
- [Stacktrace](http://paste.md-5.net/raw/payunukege)

Comment: Maven shouldn't allow that combination of source/target; the java compiler won't accept it, so Maven may be silently clamping the settings for you to -target 1.8?  I think you are getting lulled into a false sense of confidence by Maven not failing compilation immediately.

Comment: But the short answer is: default methods are a feature of Java 8, and they require support from the Java 8 VM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will divide the answer in two parts, the first regarding type inference and the second regarding default methods:

**Type inference**

In Java 7, **the type of an expression is the same, regardless of context**. So when you do:

```
Arrays.asList(new ClassMode(), new EndMode(), ...);
```

It does not create a `List<ISetting<?>>`. You could make it work by changing the `settings` type to `List<? extends ISetting<?>>`. That is, a list that can hold elements that can be a `ISetting<?>` or any subtype of it:

```
List<? extends ISetting<?>> settings = Arrays.asList(new ClassMode(), new EndMode(), ...);
```

In Java 8, assigning the resulting list to a `List<ISetting<?>>` works because of *[poly expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dlsmith/jsr335-0.6.1/D.html)*. This means that **the deduced type of some expressions can be influenced by the target type**. So when you do:

```
private List<ISetting<?>> settings = Arrays.asList(new ClassMode(), new EndMode(), ...);
```

The compiler analyses the target type and implicitly passes a type parameter to `Arrays.asList()`, which is equivalent to doing:

```
private List<ISetting<?>> settings = Arrays.<ISetting<?>>asList(new ClassMode(), new EndMode(), ...);
```

Which creates a `List<ISetting<?>>` and assigns it to `settings`. The above form also works in Java 7, if you don't want to change the `settings` type.

**Default methods**

Java 7 does not have default methods. Instead, you could create an abstract *skeletal implementation* to go together with your interface. The interface will define the type, and the skeletal implementation will provide the default functionality.

First, turn the `default` methods in your interface into regular method declarations:

```
public interface ISetting<T> {
    T getDefault();
    T value();
    void set(T value);
    String getName();

    // Former default methods:
    String getValueName();
    boolean isHidden();
    boolean isDefault();
    // etc.
}
```

Then create an abstract class to hold the default implementations:

```
public abstract class AbstractSetting<T> implements ISetting<T> {

    @Override
    public String getValueName() {
        Object obj = value();
        if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
            return ((Boolean) obj) ? "Yes" : "No";
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isHidden() {
        return false;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Now make your concrete classes implement the `ISetting<T>` interface and extend the `AbstractSetting<T>` class. For example:

```
public class ConcreteSetting extends AbstractSetting<Boolean> implements ISetting<Boolean> {
    // concrete implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! I will use the abstract skeletal implementation. Just one question though. Doesn't extending `AbstractSetting<Boolean>` automatically make it implement `ISetting<Boolean>`? I will mark this as the accepted answer once I've implemented this into my code.

Comment: @VapidLinus Glad to help! Yes, you could omit that part without a problem. I just put it there to make it clearer that `ConcreteSetting` implements `ISetting<Boolean>` and that extending `AbstractSetting<Boolean>` is just an implementation detail. This is the same style used in the `ArrayList<T>` declaration: `class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do one of the following:

- remove default modifier from `getValueName()`
- make [abstract] class instead of interface
- upgrade your platform to Java 1.8